# Centrally Aligned Equation on left part of cases

Tags: vertical-alignment, cases

I'm trying to get the following [image: what I want]
in my file but the best I can do is by using cases but that doesn't work that well

```
 S_{\sigma}(v,c) = \begin{cases}
    w \in V \mid &\text{there exists a path an alternating between v and w} \\
     &\text{ using the colors } \sigma(v) \text{ and c}.
\end{cases}
```

I get the following
[image] How do I deal with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need curly braces at both ends, I don't think a `cases` environment would be appropriate.

Here's a solution that uses a two-column `array` environment and a `\parbox` directive for the text material to the right of the tall vertical bar. I obtained the parbox's width (`0.52\textwidth`} by trial and error.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
S_{\sigma}(v,c) = 
\left\{ \begin{array}{@{} l | l @{}}
    w \in V & 
    \parbox{0.52\textwidth}{\raggedright there exists an alternating path between $v$ and $w$ using the colors $\sigma(v)$ and $c$.}
\end{array}\right\} \,.
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place the two lines into a `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
S_{\sigma}(v,c) = 
\biggl\{
    w \in V\;\bigg|
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        there exists an alternating path between\\
        $v$ and $w$ using the colors $c$ and $\sigma(v)$
    \end{tabular}
\biggr\}
\]

\end{document}
```